# Wubi install: How to increase swap size

Tags: partitioning, wubi, swap

I am trying to increase the swapfile size on my WUBI install.

I followed the answer [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_increase_my_swap_space.3F):

```
    sudo su

    swapoff -a

    cd /host/ubuntu/disks/

    mv swap.disk swap.disk.bak

    dd if=/dev/zero of=swap.disk bs=1024 count=2097152

    mkswap swap.disk

    swapon -a

    free -m
```

until I reached:

```
    mv swap.disk swap.disk.bak
```

At which point I have got got the following:

```
    root@ubuntu:/host/ubuntu/disks# mv swap.disk swap.disk.bak

    mv: cannot move `swap.disk' to `swap.disk.bak': Operation not permitted
```

My 256 M swap space is all used up. I would like to install a total of twice that. Is there a method of setting it which would not include guesswork on my part?

I followed BCBC below and now I get an error:

```
    swapon -a

    swapon: /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk: read swap header failed: Invalid argument –
```

/etc/fstab looks like:

## UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM

/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0

Fixed.

(Have to be sure to allow all processes to finish; this takes several minutes.)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should allow you to `mv` once you've turned off swap (`swapoff -a`). That should have worked...

Instead, create the new swap disk under a different name e.g. `newswap.disk` and boot back to Windows before doing the rename/move.

PS you might want to run `chkdsk` on that Windows drive as well. Just in case. File system corruption does occur on Wubi installs, and sometimes a symptom like not being able to rename a file might be an indicator. (Although this time it's probably that the swap wasn't turned off).

So you would run:

```
sudo su
cd /host/ubuntu/disks/
dd if=/dev/zero of=newswap.disk bs=1024 count=2097152
mkswap newswap.disk
```

Then reboot to Windows and replace swap.disk with newswap.disk. (But first try the original instructions again and make sure you've run `swapoff -a` and it completed without errors.)

PS you can see if the swap file is still mounted with:

```
swapon -s
```

Comment: swapon: /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk: read swap header failed: Invalid argument

Comment: Is that after you created the new swap file? Did you forget to run `mkswap`?

Comment: That got it, I forgot mkswap! One more question. I started the code with sudo sudo su, as I had the "operation not permitted" problem before, when I started with sudo su. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @DiogenesLantern When I use more than one sudo e.g. `sudo sudo su` it ignores the extras. It should be identical to `sudo su`. Not sure why it didn't work for you. Maybe a typo? Try it again and see what happens.

Comment: yes they're the same - using "sudo sudo sudo sudo su" = "sudo su".